# Wordpress skipping over designated template-{post-type}, jumping right to index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have x number of custom post types. All of these custom post types are echoed in various places on the site; viz., they are queried for and retrieved without any problems. Nonetheless, I have a page template for a few of the custom post types. All of the sudden, these `page-templates` are no longer being used for the pages themselves. For example, I have a 'team' type. The WP page is correctly designated to use the team template, and all of that associated stuff, but instead of actually using the template, it just uses `index.php`. I have refreshed the permalinks probably hundreds of time. I have also tried making `page-{post-type}` pages, and a `page.php` template, but it skips over those too. Despite all of this, the `single-{post-type}` templates still work.

I have even tried restoring my database to a time before the bug began, but eventually the bug will pop up again and persist. I'm out of ideas.

** also, the pages will work with default permalinks, but not pretty permalinks (and yes, I have checked the `.htaccess`).

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Team', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Team', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Team'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Team'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Team'),
    'new_item' => __('New Team'),
    'view_item' => __('View Team'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Team'),
    'not_found' => __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'rewrite' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
);

register_post_type('team' , $args);
```

And the template name is: `team.php`. I am sure none of this is an issue as I have worked with custom post-types and on many sites and never had an issue like this one.

UPDATE: I re-installed WP and completely re-populated a new database and am still getting the same error, so it must have something to do with my code, but as of now, I really have no idea where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out myself. It ends up that the page names were conflicting with the post types in the sense that I had a page named /team, but also a post-type named team, therefore putting the structure of /team/team-member in conflict with just /team, which also explains why single-{post-type} was still working.